# Does Spark Structured Streaming support that "Insert" Into a Hudi Table using SQL statement?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Can I make this Code work?
PS: I [KAFKA_TABLE_VIEW] is a streaming table that I have created in spark session.

```
    spark
      .readStream
      .format("hudi")
      .load(getTablePath(ODS_LOG))
      .createOrReplaceTempView("ODS_LOG_VIEW")

    toConsole(runSQL(
      s"""
         |INSERT INTO ODS_LOG_VIEW
         |SELECT
         |UUID() AS `uuid`,
         |*,
         |DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`ts`/ 1000), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS `dt`
         |FROM [KAFKA_TABLE_VIEW];
         |""".stripMargin
    ))
```

Spark: 3.3.1
Scala: 2.12
Hudi:0.12

Here are some Exception about SQL statement.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'InsertIntoStatement StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@3749c2b,hudi,List(),None,List(),None,Map(path -> file:///Users/liu/Data/20_Code/iWhaleCloud/Hudi-Demo/src/main/resources/ODS_LOG),None), hudi, [_hoodie_commit_time#60, _hoodie_commit_seqno#61, _hoodie_record_key#62, _hoodie_partition_path#63, _hoodie_file_name#64, uuid#65, common#66, start#67, page#68, actions#69, displays#70, err#71, ts#72L, dt#73], false, false;
'InsertIntoStatement StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@3749c2b,hudi,List(),None,List(),None,Map(path -> file:///Users/liu/Data/20_Code/iWhaleCloud/Hudi-Demo/src/main/resources/ODS_LOG),None), hudi, [_hoodie_commit_time#60, _hoodie_commit_seqno#61, _hoodie_record_key#62, _hoodie_partition_path#63, _hoodie_file_name#64, uuid#65, common#66, start#67, page#68, actions#69, displays#70, err#71, ts#72L, dt#73], false, false
+- Project [uuid(Some(4167610234564846665)) AS uuid#88, common#32, start#33, page#34, actions#35, displays#36, err#37, ts#38L, date_format(cast(from_unixtime(cast((cast(ts#38L as double) / cast(1000 as double)) as bigint), yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, Some(Asia/Shanghai)) as timestamp), yyyy-MM-dd, Some(Asia/Shanghai)) AS dt#89]
   +- SubqueryAlias ods_base_log
      +- View (`ODS_BASE_LOG`, [common#32,start#33,page#34,actions#35,displays#36,err#37,ts#38L])
         +- Project [data#30.common AS common#32, data#30.start AS start#33, data#30.page AS page#34, data#30.actions AS actions#35, data#30.displays AS displays#36, data#30.err AS err#37, data#30.ts AS ts#38L]
            +- Project [from_json(StructField(common,StructType(StructField(ar,StringType,true),StructField(uid,StringType,true),StructField(os,StringType,true),StructField(ch,StringType,true),StructField(is_new,StringType,true),StructField(md,StringType,true),StructField(mid,StringType,true),StructField(vc,StringType,true),StructField(ba,StringType,true)),true), StructField(start,StructType(StructField(entry,StringType,true),StructField(loading_time,LongType,false),StructField(open_ad_id,LongType,false),StructField(open_ad_ms,LongType,false),StructField(open_ad_skip_ms,LongType,false)),true), StructField(page,StructType(StructField(page_id,StringType,true),StructField(item,StringType,true),StructField(item_type,StringType,true),StructField(during_time,LongType,false),StructField(last_page_id,StringType,true),StructField(source_type,StringType,true)),true), StructField(actions,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(action_id,StringType,true),StructField(item,StringType,true),StructField(item_type,StringType,true),StructField(ts,LongType,false)),true),true), StructField(displays,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(display_type,StringType,true),StructField(item,StringType,true),StructField(item_type,StringType,true),StructField(pos_id,LongType,false),StructField(order,LongType,false)),true),true), StructField(err,StructType(StructField(error_code,StringType,true),StructField(msg,StringType,true)),true), StructField(ts,LongType,false), value#21, Some(Asia/Shanghai)) AS data#30]
               +- Project [cast(value#8 as string) AS value#21]
                  +- StreamingRelationV2 org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@416b681c, kafka, org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@46d69ca4, [startingOffsets=earliest, kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092, subscribe=ODS_BASE_LOG], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@3749c2b,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092, subscribe -> ODS_BASE_LOG, startingOffsets -> earliest),None), kafka, [key#0, value#1, topic#2, partition#3, offset#4L, timestamp#5, timestampType#6]
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "making this code work"? What is current behavior? What is desired behavior?

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin sorry, I didn't put my question clearly, I means, above code doesn't work, it'll come up some SQL exception. I wanna using the Insert SQL Statement to insert some data from a query from a kafka streaming table to a exsisting hudi streaming table. Have I made myself clear?

Comment: Please add the message of SQL error to your question (you can press "Edit")

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I added some exception throw by the code.

Comment: Your code is not self-contained https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/SREN6xFLTCmZDqMlWcRpNg Where are `getTablePath`, `ODS_LOG`, `toConsole`, `runSQL` from? Do you have reproduction? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)